# Site not completely loaded in the browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-5

I have a MVC 3 project hosted on IIS 5.1.

80% of the time everything is working fine, but often when the connection is slow, the page is not loaded completely in the user's browser. The loading finishes fast, but certain CSS definitions and images are not loaded and not displayed in the browser.

I tried it with Firefox and IE and the results are the same.

Is it IIS 5.1 that causes this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to find out why the css and images are not loaded?  E.g. with Firebug or Fiddler? It would be helpful to see what status code you get back.

Could it be that the site is accessed by my multiple users at the same time?  Since you are using IIS 5.1 I assume you are using Windows XP Professional. As far as I can remember Windows XP Professional has a limit of 10 simultaneous inbound connections. So if you access it with multiple users at the same time you might be hitting that limit as most browsers open 4 to 6 connections per domain/website.

*Edit by xsl:* Here is how you up the connection limit on IIS5 to the hard-coded maximum of 50: http://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/archive/2003/10/10/31476.aspx